# How to get data from server api in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, cross-platform

everyone. I am going to get data from server API. 
Bellow is postman screenshot.
[image: response in postman]

And I used follow code:

```
    await fetch('http://wichz.com/api/test/token', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Content-Type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            "Auth": token_variable,
        }

    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        Alert.alert('Warning!', 'Network Error.');
    });
```

But server can't accept headers, so response is that token is failed.
Then token which is used is correct and server can response from my request. 
But server can't get "Auth" field in header, and response is

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "data": null
    "error": "Invalid token"
}
```

Follow is response header in postman
[image: response header in postman]

How can I fetch data from server. Please advance me if anyone can solve this issue. Thanks.